# Ruby on Rails and Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to learn ruby on rails and ajax. I've mostly worked through this tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/
and this: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Now I'm trying to get the most basic things working so I have a foundation to build on. I would like to dynamically load content after the page loads.
I have a page that gets displayed with the following code in it (app/views/statc_pages/home):

```
<h1>StaticPages#home</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb</p>
<div name="results" id="results" class="results"></div>
```

And I have a file in app/assets/javascript/static_pages.js.coffee:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $.ajax(url: "/static_pages/test").done (html) ->  $('#results').append html
```

I have two files in app/views/static_pages/ which are test.js.erb and test.hmtl.erb with the same content. But it doesn't get added to the /home.
My static pages controller only has:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
  def test
  end
end
```

So far only the home page gets displayed. The coffeescript gets executed but the contents of /test won't get inserted. I'm not sure if the ajax code gets executed.

Edit: config/routes.rb:

```
AjaxTest::Application.routes.draw do
  get "static_pages/home"
  get "static_pages/test"
```

Edit:fixed the following previous edit:
Edit: When I change the ajax url to fetch to "test" i get:

```
Missing template static_pages/test, application/test with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/xyious/Programming/AjaxTest/app/views"
```

Edit: now chrome says that static_pages.js consists of the following:

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    return $.ajax({
      url: "test"
    }).done(function(html) {
      return $('#results').append(html);
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the console?

Comment: No error messages in log/development. Not sure if there would be another place for error messages.

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(html)`?

Comment: Added console.log(html) to the coffeescript, but I don't know how to access that. I'm on phusion passenger on apache2.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the template (view file) for your `StaticPages#test` action.

Add a file called `test.js.erb` to your `views/static_pages` directory.

Comment: There is, just copied the entry for home and changed to test. (edited question)

Comment: What files are in your `views/static_pages` directory?

Comment: I apparently made a mistake when i tried to copy the file to .js.erb and .html.erb.... they weren't in the views/static_pages directory anymore. Copied them back and get a 200 (OK) in chrome now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using firebug javascript console (or chrome dev tools, etc) to debug? does the ajax request to `/statis_pages/test` execute? and try logging the `html` variable in the javascript after the request occurs

most likely you need to respond with js format

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def test
    respond_to do |format|        
      format.js # should render app/views/static_pages/test.js.erb
    end
  end
end
```

checkout the rails casts for full details - http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised

Comment: Doesn't change anything (also tried adding {} after format.js).
There's only a line of text in test.js.erb. Does it need to be javascript ? 
The ajax request doesn't appear to be happening, but I can't be sure.

Comment: OK I lied. chrome gives me a 404 for the ajax request to static_pages/test: The requested URL /static_pages/test was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

The default dataType of jQuery's `ajax` is `script`. So basically you are send a js request to server asking for some html response.

For such case you need to change `ajax` to `get` directly, to send Ajax request as html dataType.

```
$.get(url: "/static_pages/test").done (html) ->  $('#results').append html
```

Then in controller you need to set not to render layout for ajax request.

```
def test
  if request.xhr?
     render 'test', layout: false
     return
  else
     # blah blah
  end
end
```

But, to be frankly this type of requests are okay for experiments but too troublesome in real work.

Comment: Now i get the following in chrome: No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/[object Object]"  How would you do it in real work ? is there a tutorial that explains things in detail ?